# Installing Patches in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, patch

I have a patch file that I want to install in linux. I know there is a patch command, And I tried to use it like this:

```
patch -i file --verbose
```

where file is the patch file. But it asks me for the file to be patched(to be changed):

```
Hmm...  Looks like a unified diff to me...
can't find file to patch at input line 17
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From 13fac179aa50556ba3c60790a9beb6ca9d0b1b8b Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: Andrey Vagin <avagin@openvz.org>
|Date: Fri, 28 Jan 2011 23:31:20 +0300
|Subject: [PATCH rh5] vdso: export vdso_sysctl_vsyscall
|
|Signed-off-by: Andrey Vagin <avagin@openvz.org>
|---
| arch/x86_64/vdso/vclock_gettime.c |    4 ++--
| arch/x86_64/vdso/vextern.h        |    1 +
| include/asm-x86_64/vsyscall.h     |    1 +
| 3 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
|
|diff --git a/arch/x86_64/vdso/vclock_gettime.c b/arch/x86_64/vdso/vclock_gettime.c
|index 5e15d01..3e586bf 100644
|--- a/arch/x86_64/vdso/vclock_gettime.c
|+++ b/arch/x86_64/vdso/vclock_gettime.c
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

I don't know what file should be changed so I tried to get that from the patch file itself. But of course there is no directory `arch/x86_64/vdso/`

This is the full [patch file](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=475892). Any help on how to install it?

Comment: Did you extract the kernel source first?

Comment: how and why should I do that?

Comment: Because that's what patch files are applied to.

Comment: I still don't get it. I'm not that good in using linux. But how can I do that?

Comment: The *patch* is applied to source code.  You then compile the Linux kernel and deploy it.  You are missing a lot of steps to make the *patch* useful.  In a linux shell, `uname -a` will tell you your version.  Then you need to get the source from http://www.kernel.org that matches.  You extract this to a directory and run `cat patch | patch -p1` from within the *linux* sub-directory.  By itself, this does not install it.  You need to configure, compile and install the Linux kernel after this.  See the **README** file in the source directory.

Comment: We've already had this conversation in your last question.  You're running a much newer kernel version than the one which showed this bug.  Can you run "chroot"?  If so, your system doesn't have the bug.  The problem you think you're having is not the one you're actually having.  Why don't you back up and ask for help debugging your segfault?

Answer (score 2):

A patch file like this contains the differences between two versions of text files.

This one contains changes to these source files:

```
arch/x86_64/vdso/vclock_gettime.c |    4 ++--
arch/x86_64/vdso/vextern.h        |    1 +
include/asm-x86_64/vsyscall.h     |    1 +
```

You can't install it. You can use it to patch the source code (if you have it), compile it and install the results. But I don't think that is what you want.

If you want to install bugfixes use your package manager (I guess it's 'yum' for RedHat).

Comment: I don't know how to compile it to install the results. and there is no directory starting by arch/.

can you please give more details?

Comment: Why do you want to 'install' this file at all?

Comment: It is a bug fix for seg faults caused by vdso/vsyscall.

Comment: The you have to wait until this bugfix is included in the kernel your distribution is using.
The alternative is to download the kernel sources, add the patch, build the kernel and install/use the newly built kernel.

Comment: It is not even for my distro. I got that from Redhat's bugzilla but I use Ubuntu. And I really need it soon.

Comment: Well, if the patch isn't included in Ubuntu already, follow this guide to build your own kernel:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good with patch files, but it seems to be a patch file in the 'git format'.

The easiest way to apply such files would be to

1) `git clone <path_to_kernel_sources>`
2) `git checkout 13fac179aa50556ba3c60790a9beb6ca9d0b1b8b`
3) `git apply <patch_file>`

That should take care of automatically applying it for you.
I'm not entirely sure if the commit ID `13fac179aa50556ba3c60790a9beb6ca9d0b1b8b` is the correct one. I just picked that up from the e-mail part of your post.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some more arguments to [patch(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch). In particular, try

```
 patch -p1 --verbose -i file
```